# Check if a string within a list contains a specific string with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string>` that has some items like this:

```
{"Pre Mdd LH", "Post Mdd LH", "Pre Mdd LL", "Post Mdd LL"}
```

Now I want to perform a condition that checks if an item in the list contains a specific string. something like:

`IF list contains an item that contains this_string`

To make it simple I want to check in one go if the list at least! contains for example an item that has `Mdd LH` in it.

I mean something like:

```
if(myList.Contains(str => str.Contains("Mdd LH))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I think you want [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
if (myList.Any(str => str.Contains("Mdd LH")))
```

It's well worth becoming familiar with the [LINQ standard query operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx); I would usually use those rather than implementation-specific methods (such as `List<T>.ConvertAll`) unless I was really bothered by the performance of a specific operator. (The implementation-specific methods can sometimes be more efficient by knowing the size of the result etc.)

Comment: How can we make it case insensitive search? Contains doesn't have that overload method.

Comment: @Ankur-m: You can use `IndexOf` instead, passing in a `StringComparison`. If that's not enough detail, please ask a new question (after searching for existing ones, of course).

Comment: I could do it using IndexOf. However I had to use FindIndex instead of Any. I am still looking why Any didn't work. And yes there are similar posts which I couldn't find in my first search. Thank a lot for the help!

Comment: @Ankur-m: Well if you're still confused, I suggest you ask a new question - if you don't need the index, then Any really should work.

Comment: I will create a question then after some more analysis.

Comment: I was actually able to understand the issue and so didn't create a new question. I used below to get it working:
searchText.Any(x => x.IndexOf(eachWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0.
Before I was using < 0 (because I needed no-match condition) and it always returned 'True'. I should have used == 0.
I finally changed it to 'exact word' match by changing the code to:
searchText.Any(x => x.IndexOf(string.Format(" {0} ", eachWord), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) of course by padding spaces at start and end of my input strings.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Why does it returns true when an empty string if tried to be found in a list of strings where there is no empty string ? i.e. if (list.Any(str => str.Contains(val))) returns true if 'val' is an empty string and 'list' does not contains any empty string. https://dotnetfiddle.net/JnE3Fe

Comment: @ManikArora: Because any string "contains" the empty string. That's more about `string.Contains` than about `Any`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 14):

That should be easy enough

```
if( myList.Any( s => s.Contains(stringToCheck))){
  //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
bool matchFound = myList.Any(s => s.Contains("Mdd LH"));
```

The `Any()` will [stop searching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx#Anchor_2) the moment it finds a match, so is quite efficient for this task.

Answer (score 7):

LINQ Any() would do the job:

```
bool contains = myList.Any(s => s.Contains(pattern));
```

[Any(), MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition

Answer (score 3):

If yoou use Contains, you could get false positives.
Suppose you have a string that contains such text: "My text data Mdd LH"
Using Contains method, this method will return true for call.
The approach is use equals operator:

`bool exists = myStringList.Any(c=>c == "Mdd LH")`

Comment: That is exactly what the poster was trying to accomplish, a 'like' in sql, so these would be 'positive positives' I guess, no equals necessary.