# purging users with an automated c# irc bot

Tags: c#, irc, spam-prevention, twitch, purge

I am making a twitch chat bot with c# and I would like to know how I can purge/timeout users that are spamming or using banned words. I have searched everywhere i can to find a solution for this, but I can not find an answer anywhere.

Comment: if there is a way to ban then quickly unban the user, or even time out the user for a small amount of time, that will work also.

Comment: basically i just want to know how to get rid of a specific user's messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to provide any implementation in your question, so I will make some assumptions. I assume that you have a list of banned words in a `List<String>` object called `bannedWords`, and are considering spam as a message that exceeds a given number of characters.

You have it correct that in order to time out someone, you need to send `.timeout [user] [number of seconds]`, and this will 'delete' any messages they've sent (although users can simply click the <message deleted> link to see the original message).

One way you could do this is by doing the following:

```
// Code attribution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9032686/2605758    
if (bannedWords.Any(str => str.Contains(message)) || message.Length >= maxLength)
{
    /* use whatever method you use to send a message to your channel */
    SendMessage(".timeout " + userNick + " 1"); 
}
```

Comment: Also, for future reference, it's a good idea to provide code examples of what you have for the relevant parts of your program so far (even if they're not working - non-working code is better than no code at all!), so that we have a better idea of what you plan to do, and what kind of implementation you require.

Comment: thank you for the help on formatting, i will keep all of that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem, but if anyone else has the same problem you just simply send ".timeout [user] 1"