# To find if a list contains a specific string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a model called results. I need to get those values from the results list which contain this particular string.

```
List<Search> results = new List<Search>();

results = db.Users.Select(f => new Search{ Name = f.Name, Type = f.OrganizationType.Name, County = f.County.Name }).ToList();

results = results.Where(w => (model.Name == null || w.Name.Contains(model.Name))).ToList();
```

While the first result query returns 5000 rows, the second one returns 0. What i am trying to do in the second query is if the Name is null or if the Name contains part of a string, add it to the results list.
Am I missing something?

I did check a couple of links which basically asked me to do the same like [Check if a string within a list contains a specific string with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032655/check-if-a-string-within-a-list-contains-a-specific-string-with-linq)

I have checked the value for model.Name and it shows up properly. Also the query works if there is no search string that is when Model.Name = null, I get all the records

Comment: It's bad practice to fetch all rows into the ram and filter afterwards. Your sql server should already do the job to reduce cpu/network load, overhead and ram usage.

Comment: How do we know that the results actually contain `model.Name`?  Where is that set?  We can't be sure...also, you aren't dealing with casing issues.  `Aaron` is not the same as `aaron`.

Comment: Who is `model` field, a `Search` variable?

Comment: @octavioccl Yes it is a search field and it is being populated right

Comment: The "first query" does not filter anything, it just take all results from datasource and maps them to Search objects

Comment: Regarding the second, please be careful to case, and also be sure that model.Name can really be equal to null. I suspect it can be empty string instead, which ruins your search logic.

Comment: @fubo Is there a case insensitive Contains ?

Comment: @The_Outsider sure `"foo".IndexOf("FOO",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0`

Comment: You can call .ToUpper for each side of comparison. String.Equals(row.Name, "test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) is also translated in linq to sql but of course does not behave as Contains()

Answer (score 1):

Consider this statement: `Name is null or if the Name contains part of a string` I hope you need to check an item in `db.Users` for null and Contains. One more thing I have to add here is- if `x.Name` is null then the following `.Contains` will raise `NullReferanceException` So you have to consider that as well. Now take a look into the following query:

```
List<Search> results = db.Users.Where(x=> x.Name==null || (x.Name !=null && x.Name.Contains(model.Name)))
                               .Select(f => new Search{ Name = f.Name, Type = f.OrganizationType.Name, County = f.County.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: `Contains('foo')`  is translated into `Like'%foo%'` so there should be no `ToLower()` required because `Like` is already case insensitive

Comment: While I understand there might be performance issues by doing it in two queries, how is my query different to yours?

Comment: @The_Outsider `ToList()` writes the result into your ram. You do it in your application, un-lucky does it in the sql query

Comment: @fubo So does it remove the case sensitive issue of the contains?

Comment: @fubo: thanks for the new information `Contains('foo') is translated into Like'%foo%'`. Let me remove the `.ToLower()` and update the answer