# Checking if database column contains, starts with or ends with any of list items inside a where clause of an EF query doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to retrieve from database the list of products which names contains, starts with or ends with any of list elements that I pass as parameter to the method executing the query.

I've tried both Linq approaches (method and query syntax)

Here is the relevant code of Linq method query, names being List of names passed as argument to the method:

```
var query =  _dbContext.Products
                       .Where(p => p.IdExternalProduct == null && 
                                   names.Any(name => p.ProductName.Contains(name)))
                       .Select(item => new ProductEntity() { Uuid = item.Uuid, Code = item.Code});
```

or

```
var query =  _dbContext.Products
                       .Where(p => p.IdExternalProduct == null && 
                                   names.Any(name => p.ProductName.StartsWith(name)))
                       .Select(item => new ProductEntity() { Uuid = item.Uuid, Code = item.Code});
```

And here is the query syntax approach:

```
IQueryable<ProductEntity> query = (
                        from p in _dbContext.Products
                        where 
                            p.IdExternalProduct == null &&
                            (names != null && names.Count > 0 ? names.Any(name => p.ProductName.Contains(name)) : true)
                        select new ProductEntity()
                        {
                          Uuid = p.Uuid,
                          Code = p.Code
                        }
```

The exact same query works when I try with `Equals` instead of `Contains`, `StartsWith` or `EndsWith`.

I searched a lot and found a lot of resources but no solution worked for me.

Here are two related Stack overflow's questions where Jon Skeet recommends the same implementation.

[Check if a string within a list contains a specific string with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032655/check-if-a-string-within-a-list-contains-a-specific-string-with-linq)

[Proper LINQ where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359980/proper-linq-where-clauses)

I'm using the version 6.0.10 of Entity Framework and SQL Server provider.

But it's seems that these formulas cannot be translated, throwing an exception with the following message:

> The LINQ expression 'name => EntityShaperExpression:
> Service.Product.Products
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .ProductName.Contains(name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: There's often a _SQL Function_ that will do the trick. Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

Comment: @Flydog57 The functions are well supported by EF, i'm getting the exception because of the list (Any), the simple use case *p.ProductName.Contains(name)* works well

Comment: This logic should be on database side

Comment: @LeandroBardelli The sql equivelent of my request is *where product_name like 'test1%' OR product_name like 'test2%' OR product_name like 'test3%'* I don't see any logic to handle on database side

Comment: I know it can be translated, that's the way EF works, but in my humble opinion, for architecture concerns, this should be at db side.

Comment: I finally found a workaround by using the LinqKit PredicateBuilder, this way, the predicates gets translated, put it as comment because it's not a solution to my initial problem. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Jon Skeet recommends this implementation in the other SO answers is because it refers to `IEnumerable` queries (linq-to-object) and not `IQueryable` queries (linq-to-entities). Linq-to-object executes on in-memory objects, and will actually execute the `string.Contains` method. Methods given to EF are not actually executed, they are *translated* into SQL statements, and efcore 6 does not know how to translate your statement, especially the `name` variable that comes from a linq-to-object lambda in the `IEnumerable.Any` call.

Most developper forget that `IQueryable<T>` is a cumulative type, and you can aggregate predicates on it. A simple solution would be to union queries from each name, and distinct all results:

```cs
var query = names.Select(name => _dbContext.Products
    .Where(product => product.IdExternalProduct == null)
    .Where(product => product.ProductName.Contains(name)))
  .Aggregate(Queryable.Union)
  .Distinct()
  .Select(product => new ProductEntity(...));
```

This query produces the following statement:

```
DECLARE @__name_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'a';
DECLARE @__name_1 nvarchar(4000) = N'b';

SELECT DISTINCT [t].[Id], [t].[IdExternalProduct], [t].[ProductName]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[IdExternalProduct], [p].[ProductName]
    FROM [Products] AS [p]
    WHERE ([p].[IdExternalProduct] IS NULL) AND ((@__name_0 LIKE N'') OR CHARINDEX(@__name_0, [p].[ProductName]) > 0)
    UNION
    SELECT [p0].[Id], [p0].[IdExternalProduct], [p0].[ProductName]
    FROM [Products] AS [p0]
    WHERE ([p0].[IdExternalProduct] IS NULL) AND ((@__name_1 LIKE N'') OR CHARINDEX(@__name_1, [p0].[ProductName]) > 0)
) AS [t]
```

Comment: The solution your suggest doesn't match with the situation I described in the question, I'm checking if productName column contains any of LIST string items, not just one string value as it's shown in your solution (name), applying the contains on one string value works well for me too.

Comment: No, the snippet will return all entries that match *any* of the values in the `names` collection.

Comment: See edit for the generated SQL statement