# C# Case insensitive string comparison

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that holds a few strings(names). For this example.
It will hold:

- TeSt1
- TeSt2
- TeSt3

And I'm trying to check if that list has one of those. And I'm doing this like this at the moment:

```
if (list.Contains(test2))
{

}
```

But I need it to be case insensitive.. But how can I do that? in an if statement.

Comment: See [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107765/how-to-ignore-the-case-sensitivity-in-liststring). Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: For simple, non-accented strings, such as the english language, simple append what Gigi suggests: `list.Contains("test2", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Contains` method has an overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer`. You can give it one by doing the following:

```
 if (list.Contains(test2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))  
 {  
     // do something  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf has a parameter for case insensitive search

```
culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(toSearch, word, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

where culture is the instance of CultureInfo describing the language that the text is written in.

You can loop through the list and see if it each list entry matches the search.

Comment: `CompareInfo.IndexOf` doesn't take a list, it searches for a substring within another string.

Comment: @hvd. I know. I made my answer clearer by stating that you have loop through the list to compare

Comment: But you shouldn't be checking for substrings at all, only for complete matches.

Answer (score -2):

Make your `list`  lower case......and

```
if (list.Contains(test2.ToLower()))
{

}
```

Comment: Thats bad, why would he want to make his list lower case?

Comment: Data alteration to check a condition? Sounds good enough.

Comment: Will fail in culture specific comparison cases, see [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)