# Compare list<sting> with foreach loop ignoring case c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application can compare two lsts of data the user inputs. Currently however, if two values are the same but one is upper case the application classes this as not a match.

Now I have used `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` before but I am unsure of how to add this within a foreach loop.

My current code is as follows;

```
List<string> mylistA = new List<string>();
List<string> mylistB = new List<string>();

if (listATextBox.LineCount > 0) 
    for (int i = 1; i <= listATextBox.LineCount; i++) 
        mylistA.Add(listATextBox.GetLineText(i - 1).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());

if (listBTextBox.LineCount > 0) 
    for (int i = 1; i <= listBTextBox.LineCount; i++) 
        mylistB.Add(listBTextBox.GetLineText(i - 1).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Trim());

foreach (string line in mylistA)
{             
    if (mylistB.Contains(line))
    {
            ResultsToDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Comment: While compiling your new lists, just ToUpper the values, if you dont care about case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107765/how-to-ignore-the-case-sensitivity-in-liststring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) with this comparer as parameter instead of [`List.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (string line in mylistA)
{
    if (mylistB.Contains(line, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ResultsToDocument();
    }
}
```

A more efficient approach would be `Intersect` which also has this overload:

```
foreach(string line in mylistA.Intersect(mylistB, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     ResultsToDocument(); // does this make sense, not passing the line?
```

Comment: yeah this does make sense, so you don't have to pass the line and the check is done at the 'foreach' and you don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: One thing you have to be careful with when using `intersect` is that if there are duplicates in `mylistA` it will not generate duplicates in the result. Like the loop in the question will.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach (string line in mylistA)
{
    if (mylistB.Any(b => b.Equals(line, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        ResultsToDocument();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For better performance and readability you can use `Intersect`

```
foreach (var element in mylistA.Intersect(mylistB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   ResultsToDocument();
```

If there are duplicates in `mylistA` that needs to be preserved. Using a hashset for the lookup would be the right way to go and would have the same performance as the intersect solution.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(mylistB, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
foreach (string line in mylistA)
{             
    if (set.Contains(line))
    {
         ResultsToDocument();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd go with:

```
    foreach (string lineA in mylistA)
    {     
       foreach (string lineB in mylistB)
       {                     
            if (lineB.ToUpper() == lineA.ToUpper())
            {
                  ResultsToDocument();
            }
       }
    }
```

but there are probably better solutions to achieve the same result