# Using List.Contains method to find a string returns false but manual comparison return true

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-comparison

I have a list of strings and I am trying to determine whether one of them match a needle string. That list of strings contains the needle at the first index, and my code has the following behavior:

```
listOfStrings.Contains(needle); // return false
listOfStrings[0] == needle; // return true
```

Why does the Contains method have a different behavior than the default comparison beahavior, and what should I modify so that it has the same be havior?

To give more insight about the problem I am facing, I am handling strings which come from WinForm textboxes. They represent input paths and a destination folder.

```
        if (!destinationPath.EndsWith("\\"))
        {
            destinationPath += "\\";
        }
        List<string> inputDirectories = new List<string>(inputPaths.Length);
        foreach (string path in inputPaths)
        {
            inputDirectories.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(path).ToLower());
        }

        bool comparison1 = inputDirectories[0] == Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath.ToLower()); // return true
        bool comparison2 = inputDirectories.Contains(Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath.ToLower())); // return false
```

Comment: We need some examples to look at. This isn't enough information.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information about the strings being used. A couple examples.

Comment: Don't make the people you're asking for help have to guess what the problem is; give a *clear, short example that compiles and demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: I edited the question to provide precise examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what Type your list is, but if it's an `ArrayList` or a `List<object>` the comparison will give a different result from `List<string>`, because the `Compare` method will compare objects rather than strings.

To understand this, try running the following code:

```
string s1 = "A";
string s2 = "AB";

s1 += "B";

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);  // True 
Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s2); // False
```

`s1` and `s2` are equal when compared as strings, but are different objects.

If you are already using `List<string>` and are looking for a case-insensitive Contains, try the technique in [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107765/how-to-ignore-the-case-sensitivity-in-liststring).

Comment: Alright I got it thank you for your precise answer, is there a method when using a List<string> to compare the strings based on their value rather than their reference? Or should ArrayList be used over List<string> for this purpose?

Comment: @Toto: The only scenario you should use ArrayList is you've been kidnapped by time travelers, taken to the past, and are stuck in a world that only has C# 1.0. Always use the generic type.

Comment: How does this explain why comparison1 is true and comparison2 is false in the original question?